# Black boxes all over Chrome for Windows

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, rendering

I'm trying to understand these strange rendering error boxes that are too big to be ignored. This seems to happen on Chrome in Windows 7 (my testing isn't too elaborate) and nowhere else. When I attempt to inspect, they all disappear. This could be some kind of video card issue as I'm using some pretty advanced CSS3 transitions that could mess up memory. In any case, if someone could offer advice on what I could do to fix, I'm at a loss. The site is www.crane-usa.com

Comment: Are you using -webkit-transform with the transitions? I've noticed some re-paint glitches in Chrome when rotating and scaling elements. If that's the case you're probably best off trying to simplify the test case as much as possible and then raise it on the Chrome issue tracker.

Comment: I see no problem in Chrome on Win7 virtualized using VirtualBox on Ubuntu (and no problem on Chrome on Ubuntu).

Comment: Your humidifiers are being "sent to back" when I click the arrow.  This might be part of the problem, as I can see the frame of the greyed pictures obscuring the humidifier as it leaves the window.  You should make sure the product pictures are "always on top."  I'm in Firefox.

Comment: The only one that works properly is the red fireplace heater.  Find out what you're doing there, and do it the same way on the others.

Comment: It looks fine in my Chrome.  I know that there can be different behavior though depending on which hardware acceleration settings are on.  Browse to `chrome://flags/` to see which you have enabled, and maybe try switching them on or off to see if one of them is the cause.

Comment: It might help to add screenshots to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue with our site using 21.0.1180.89 and 21.0.1180.79. Problem is in Windows 7, Mac OS X latest, Ubuntu and in Chrome frame running in IE9. IE9 with Chrome frame disabled works fine. The problems are intermittent and unrepeatable. Inspect element removes the problem as you say. I tried disabling GPU compositing via chrome://flags but that didn't fix the issue.

We and our users have only been seeing these issues since approx Aug 27, 2012, 3 days ago. I took a look in crbugs.com and found that this seems to have existed for a couple of weeks already. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143647

Sorry our site is not public so I can't post our url but you're not alone.